Create a stable link for GitLab release assets
I trying to get my app published on Fdroid and got stuck with creating a stable/predictable link to my apk release. I went through the gitlab documentations but I am really confused. Any simple ways to use gitlab web UI to create a predictable link to my latest apk releases?
I have checked this: https://gitlab.com/fdroid/wiki/-/wikis/How-to-create-a-stable-link-for-GitLab-release-assets but did not work.
here is my app repo: https://gitlab.com/bencyric/cs-137-app-cyric
I would appreciate any help understanding how to generate a stable link to my apk file in the release.

Please edit to include what "did not work", and if there is an error message also add that.
